# CKEdit 4.13.1 fresh install won't run sample code properly on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor4.x

Firefox runs the sample OK. No errors.

With the Chrome Browser the sample page comes up but the editor box is missing. Chrome says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
at new $ (ckeditor.js:797)
at Object.beforeInit (ckeditor.js:800)
at Object.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:286)
at e (ckeditor.js:265)
at Object.load (ckeditor.js:265)
at ckeditor.js:286
at CKEDITOR.resourceManager.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:272)
at CKEDITOR.resourceManager.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:270)
at e (ckeditor.js:265)
at Object.load (ckeditor.js:265)
```

What should I do? -- btw the OS is Xubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had downloaded the basic editor first and decided I wanted more features so I deleted everything and then downloaded a more feature rich package.

Chrome was caching some of the code and apparently the two versions are not compatible.

When I moved the sample code to a new directory on the server it functioned fine. I just can't make Chrome dump it's cache and reload all assets. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Refresh doesn't do it.

Comment: 1 Right-click somewhere on the page and choose Inspect Element; the dev console will appear. 2 Go to the "Application" tab up top. (You may have to make the dev console super wide to see this but it's there.) 3 Find "Clear storage" in the sidebar.